# Excel Formula To Count The Number Of Times a Text Appeared in a Cell

Tags: excel

I am looking for an Excel formula using IF function to Count the Number of Times a specific text appeared in a range of cells.
I do not want the COUNTIF formula. I want the formula to be built using IF function.

Any suggestion guys!! I would be really grateful.

Comment: Those conditions make this sound like homework...

Comment: What is problem with `COUNTIF()` formula? State your problem clearly then get solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how many times "f" appears in cell F7:

```
=LEN(F7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F7,"f",""))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I appreciate it.. But I am looking for a formula where from a range of cells it should give the count of each item in that range.

Comment: Have in mind that before you ask anything it ll be better to make a research before. :-)

Comment: I did, but i could only find the COUNTIF formula evrywhere. It has to perform the same function what the COUNTIF does, but using the IF statement.

Comment: if you change formula to `=SUM(LEN(F7:F10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F7:F10,"f","")))` then press crtl + shift + return you count how many times "f" appears in range F7:F10

Comment: @Amreen Please explain why you need solution with `IF()` formula. One problem can be solved in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this if you really must use IF statement:

This will show you the number of "AA" occurrences in a range B2:G2 - look at the picture

{=SUM(IF(B2:G2="AA",1,0))}

Please remember that this is an array formula, so to execute it you'll need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0fy6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I find this request somewhat absurd. But if you really must:

Use if the character needed  would only appear once in any given cell and there would be no other chars besides this char when found in a cell:
`=LEN(CONCAT(IF(F1:M1="F","F","")))`.
For a set of characters use this:
`=(LEN(CONCAT(IF(F1:M1="F","F",""))))/LEN(chars)`

Evaluates whether a range has the character, return character if it has it and blank if not. concatenates resultant range and calculates its length.

If other chars may appear in the cell then thats another story

Comment: If you want the latter, Comment and Ill then elaborate